# Wordpress cloudflare upload limit

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

So currently I'm running latest version of wordpress, apache 2.2 and cloudflare. The thing is I want to upload files larger than 100MB (this is free cloudflare limit for uploads) by using wp-admin.

I have tried to add page rule for /wp-admin/* and disable everything I can, but I still can't upload anything larger than 100MB.

I think I should move wp-admin on subdomain and then disable clouldflare for that subdomain. Tried some htaccess rules with no luck.

What is your suggestions guys? Thank you.

Comment: Or upload files larger than 100MB with FTP software

Comment: This won't work because uploaded files are set as attachments for posts.

Comment: In all cases, your solution (disable clouldflare for that subdomain) seems to me the only possibility...

Answer (score 2):

So I came up with this..

```
Enabled cloudflare for example.com
Disabled cloudflare for www.example.com
```

Updated my wordpress settings so my wp-admin would be www.example.com/wp-admin/

```
add_filter('admin_url', 'my_new_admin_url');
function my_new_admin_url($url)
{
    $url = str_replace('http://example.com','http://www.example.com',$url);
    return $url;
}
```

Now I don't care about cloudflare 100MB limit on my wp-admin.

Answer (score -1):

This has a long time now, but I found another workaround.

In Cloudflare with the free plan, you can create **Page Rules**

Just create a Page Rule for `/wp-admin/*` disabling Apps, Security, Cache and Performance. This was my configuration:

[image: My cloudflare configuration]